How to attach a user into a module that updates content?
I have build a module that reads content from an API and then adds/edits this content in Drupal 10.
What I would like to do, is when it edits or creates content, to show as a specific Drupal user so that it makes it a bit more clear of which nodes it did touch.
I was considering creating the user on Module installation, but that would be a bit insecure as the user password will have to be hardcoded.
So, instead I'm thinking to create the user manually, and then make my module to search for the id of a specific named user.
What would be the best way to that?
Ideal solution would be to have a virtual user name of the module name, but I am not sure if that is even possible.
Thank you

An alternative would be to add meta information to all the affected nodes.  For example, the Feeds module adds a __feeds_item table for each entity type subject to Feeds import, which stores information about how the entities were imported.  Setting a user is probably a lot simpler; I'm just noting this here as another idea.

Require selecting a user as part of module configuration.

Meaning? Can you add an example configuration for that to work?

Does your module have a settings form?

no, there is no settings form, it does have module_name.install file.
I see, what you mean now though. That may just work out.

You don't even need a settings form. The most minimalist solution would be a mymodule/config/install/mymodule.settings.yml with a user_id: 1 key-value pair.
